# HQL query one-to-many relationship stored in a map

Tags: java, mysql, hql

I have a database with managers and employees, where one manager can have many employees or none, and each employee can only have one manager. Is there a way to query the database to return a map such as Map < manager, List< employee > > ?

I know I could create a loop querying one manager at a time and return a list of their employees saving that in the map but, with a large database this would be extremely inefficient.

I know if I pass one manager at a time I could write a outer right query such as

```
SELECT m.managerName, e.employeeName FROM Manager m NATURAL RIGHT OUTER JOIN employee e WHERE m.managerName = '';
```

but putting this in a loop would take to long.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to query the database to return a map such as Map < manager, List< employee > > ?

I am assuming you need to a map to get the employees of each manager? Have you tried One-to-Many mapping from the manager to the employees? Then each manager entity has its own list of employees.

For example - http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/